# create a class with music concert python

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

Build a program that implements the following requirements. The example is centered
around music:

- class instrument has a type, has a sound, and plays that sound (print a string, don't
  actually play music).
- class piano is an instrument, has a number of keys, and plays "beautiful music on "
  this many keys (print a string, don't actually play music).
- class violin is an instrument and plays "beautiful music" (print a string, don't actually
  play music).
- a Person has a name.
- a musician is a person who has an instrument and plays this instrument.
- an orchestra has a list of musicians and plays a concert where all musicians play
  music.

i have tried doing this but i am stuck at the class musician i dont know what to do next.

```
class Instrument:
    sound: str
    def __init__(self, type, sound):
        self.type = type
        self.sound = sound
        
    def Playinstrument(self):
         return f"This {self.type} sounds like {self.sound}"
     
        
class Piano(Instrument):
    numberofkeys: int
    
    def __init__(self, type, sound, numberofkeys ):
        self.type = type
        self.sound = sound
        self.numberofkeys = numberofkeys
        
    def Playinstrument(self):
        return f"this {self.type} plays beautiful music on these {self.numberofkeys} keys"
    
    
class Violin(Instrument):
     def __init__(self, type, sound):
         self.type = type
         self.sound = sound
         
     def Playinstrument(self):
          return print("beautiful music")
    
class Person:
    name: str
    
    def __init__(self, name = ""):
        self.name = name
        
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name    
    
    
class musician(Intstrument):
    musician: str
    def __init__(self, )
```

Comment: `class musician(Intstrument):` is saying that a musician is a kind of instrument

Answer (score 1):

You basically have to follow precisely the instructions given:

- class `Instrument` has a `type`, has a `sound`, and `plays` that sound (print a string, don't actually play music).
- class `Piano` is an `Instrument`, has a `number of keys`, and `plays` "beautiful music on " this many keys (print a string, don't actually play music).
- class `Violin` is an `Instrument` and `plays` "beautiful music" (print a string, don't actually play music).
- a `Person` has a `name`.
- a `Musician` is a `Person` who has an `Instrument` and `plays` this `Instrument`.
- an `Orchestra` has a `list` of `Musicians` and `plays` a concert where all musicians play music.

Here I took each description and used it as the `docstring` for the `class`; then I followed the instructions.

```
class Instrument:
    """has a type, has a sound, and plays that sound 
    (print a string, don't actually play music)
    """
    def __init__(self, instrument_type, sound):
        self.instrument_type = instrument_type
        self.sound = sound
        
    def play(self):
        print(f'{self.instrument_type}, and plays {self.sound}', end=' ')
      

class Piano(Instrument):
    """an instrument, has a number of keys, and plays 
    'beautiful music on ' this many keys"""
    def __init__(self, num_keys):
        super().__init__('Piano', 'beautiful music')
        self.num_keys = num_keys
        
    def play(self):
        super().play()
        print(f'on {self.num_keys} keys', end=' ')
        
  
class Violin(Instrument):
    """an instrument and plays 'beautiful music'
    """
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('Violin', 'beautiful music')
    
    # uses the `play` method of the superclass

    
class Person:
    """a Person has a name.
    """
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name


class Musician(Person):
    """a musician is a person who has an instrument 
    and plays this instrument
    """
    def __init__(self, name, instrument):
        super().__init__(name)
        self.instrument = instrument
        
    def play(self):
        print(f'{self.name} is playing the', end=' ')
        self.instrument.play()
       

class Orchestra:
    """an orchestra has a list of musicians and 
    plays a concert where all musicians play music
    """
    def __init__(self, musicians):
        self.musicians = musicians[:]
    def play(self):
        for musician in self.musicians:
            musician.play()
            print()
        

paul = Musician('Paul', Piano(840))   # that's a big Piano! ;-)           
mary = Musician('Mary', Violin())              
jack = Musician('Jack', Violin())  

orchestra = Orchestra([paul,mary, jack])
orchestra.play()
```

#### output:

```
Paul is playing the Piano, and plays beautiful music on 840 keys 
Mary is playing the Violin, and plays beautiful music 
Jack is playing the Violin, and plays beautiful music
```